# How to assign a type annotation to a class? Dynamic Property Group

Tags: python, add-on

Hi I’m running on windows 10 with blender 2.82

I keep getting these annotation type warnings which I understand are common but not breaking for addons that have compatibility, however, when trying to run blender in the background it becomes breaking.

```
Warning: class WM_OT_import_modal contains a property that should be an annotation!
c:\Users\Willard\Desktop\blender\2.82\scripts\addons\sketchfab_init_.py:1648
assign as a type annotation: WM_OT_import_modal.gltf_path
assign as a type annotation: WM_OT_import_modal.uid
You are using the latest version(1.3.1)
ERROR (wm.operator): c:\b\win64_cmake_vs2017\win64_cmake_vs2017\blender.git\source\blender\windowmanager\intern\wm_event_system.c:1486 wm_operator_invoke: invalid operator call ‘WM_OT_import_modal’
```

This is where the operator is called-

```
def import_model(gltf_path, uid):
    bpy.ops.wm.import_modal('INVOKE_DEFAULT', gltf_path=gltf_path, uid=uid)
```

Below is the class in the addon throwing the error.

```
class ImportModalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.import_modal"
    bl_label = "Import glTF model into Sketchfab"
    bl_options = {'INTERNAL'}

    gltf_path = StringProperty()
    uid = StringProperty()

    def exectue(self, context):
        print('IMPORT')
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        bpy.context.scene.render.engine = Version.ENGINE
        gltf_importer = glTFImporter(self.gltf_path, Log.default())
        success, txt = gltf_importer.read()
        if not success:
            print('Failed to read GLTF')
        try:
            old_objects = [o.name for o in bpy.data.objects] # Get the current objects inorder to find the new node hierarchy
            BlenderGlTF.create(gltf_importer, root_name=Utils.make_model_name(gltf_importer.data))
            set_import_status('')
            Utils.clean_downloaded_model_dir(self.uid)
            Utils.clean_node_hierarchy([o for o in bpy.data.objects if o.name not in old_objects])
            return {'FINISHED'}
        except Exception:
            import traceback
            print(traceback.format_exc())
            set_import_status('')
            return {'FINISHED'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        set_import_status('Importing...')
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
```

It would seem I just need to assign the properties “gltf_path” and “uid” as a type annotation to fix my error, but I can not conceive of how to do this.

Comment: Just replace the assignment operator `=` by `:`, that's it. https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons BTW: I'd suggest take the [tour] to learn about how this site works.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response I will take the tour, my apologies for breaking site rules. I came across your suggestion before. It does stop my warning of setting type as an annotation but I still receive my error ERROR (wm.operator): c:\b\win64_cmake_vs2017\win64_cmake_vs2017\blender.git\source\blender\windowmanager\intern\wm_event_system.c:1486 wm_operator_invoke: invalid operator call ‘WM_OT_import_modal’  I guess my bigger problem is not from the warning

Comment: Yeah, the first one is a warning, the other one is an error. According to the error message there is something wrong in your declaration of the operator *or* how you call the `WM_OT_import_modal` operator... Recommend add the complete code of the operator to your question to test.

Comment: I updated my original post to include the entire operator and line that the operator is called from

Comment: Can you  invoke modal operators in bg mode?

Comment: I think you nailed the problem, I tried some other modal operators and received errors from my source code as well. I guess I should try to put these features into another operator structure?