# Properties don't show up on panel

Tags: interface, properties, panel

I was following this tutorial to make a simple calculator in blender (v3.3.1), my code is almost if not completely identical to that of the recording but unlike the tutorial's mine does not seem to work. For starters the properties (value1, value2) I coded into the panel are not showing up in the UI. On top of that, after running the code and clicking on the only button that does show up (operator "some.thing") it returns the following error message:

*Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\Calculator.py", line 49, in execute
TypeError: type _PropertyDeferred doesn't define **round** method*

Here's the entire code:

```
import bpy
from math import *

from bpy.types import (
        Panel, 
        Operator, 
        PropertyGroup
        )
    
from bpy.props import (
        StringProperty, 
        PointerProperty, 
        FloatProperty
        )


class TextPanel(Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Calculate"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Math addon"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        
        scene = context.scene.your_properties
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(scene, 'value1')
        col.operator('some.thing')
        col.prop(scene, 'value2')
        col = layout.column()


class TextOperator(Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "some.thing"
    bl_label = "+" #Text on button
    bl_description = ""
    
    def execute (self, context):
        scene = context.scene.your_properties
        string = scene.string
        value1 = scene.value1
        value2 = scene.value2
        bpy.ops.object.text_add()
        obj = bpy.context.object
        obj.data.body = str(round(value1, 2)) + "+" + str(round(value2, 2)) + "=" + str(round(value1+value2, 3))
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
class addon_Properties(PropertyGroup):
    
    string = StringProperty(
        name = "Value",
        description = "name of the object to add",
        default = ""
        )
    
    value1 = FloatProperty(
        name = "Value",
        description = "value to add",
        default = 1
        )
    
    value2 = FloatProperty(
        name = "Value",
        description = "value to add",
        default = 1
        )

reg_list = (TextPanel, TextOperator, addon_Properties)


def register():
    for clss in reg_list:
        bpy.utils.register_class(clss)
    bpy.types.Scene.your_properties = PointerProperty(type=addon_Properties)

def unregister():
    for clss in reg_list:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(clss)
    del bpy.types.Scene.your_properties


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

I've done my best to try to look for differences with the original (fully functional) code the tutorial writes but I can't find any.
Thank you in advance for your help, I'm very new to python so even if i did find some posts with similar resolved problems I was not able to pinpoint how those solutions could apply to my issue.
Cheers!

Comment: Hello ! This is a classic mistake when copying a script from the pre 2.80 era : replace your property statements with annotations, you need to swap equal signs for `:` (ie replace `value1 = FloatProperty...` with `value1: FloatProperty...` and so on)

Comment: see https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/218435/how-to-assign-a-type-annotation-to-a-class-dynamic-property-group

Comment: @Gorgious Thank you so much, worked like a charm! What a weird little change they made there!

Comment: Hi Daniel, glad it's fixed! This question turns out to be a duplicate, so is closed to keep the archive tidy. Nothing personal :)